# How can I programmatically modify an embedded bar/column chart with VBA?

Tags: vba, charts, ms-office, spreadsheet

I'm creating a ProcessBook display that populates an embedded Microsoft Office 11.0 Spreadsheet object (Office 2003) with a set of entries. I'm then calculating aggregate data about them; this aggregate data should not be visible in spreadsheet form onscreen, but does need to be used to generate a bar chart. The data is currently being used to populate a separate Microsoft Office 11.0 Spreadsheet object. It's organized such that the title of each bar chart is in column A and the corresponding value is in column B.

Since this is ProcessBook, I've had some difficulty even gaining access to embedded objects, but I've managed to embed and gain access to a ChartSpace object, as well as a child [ChChart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa205365(v=office.11).aspx) object. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to either manually set the values of the bars or how to use the `.SetData` or `.SetSpreadsheetData` methods to point it to an object that I've populated.

Accessing the ChartSpace object is pretty straightforward: `ThisDisplay.ChartSpace1`
I can then add a Chart and access it fairly easily:

`Dim objChart as ChChart

Set objChart = ThisDisplay.ChartSpace1.Charts.Add(0)`

I can access my spreadsheet values pretty easily as well:

`strBarName = ThisDisplay.sstChartData.Range("A2").Value

intBarVal = ThisDisplay.sstChartData.Range("B2").Value`

How do I actually set the data source or manually set the values of the bars in the ChChart object? Alternatively, how do I use a different object to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently persistence is the key here. I managed to determine how to both add values manually and how to refer to the existing spreadsheet object. Both examples take heavily from the online ChChart documentation; I guess I was just tired when I attempted it in the first place and must have mistyped something somewhere.

```
Public Sub AddValuesToChartManually()  
Dim objChart As ChChart  
With ThisDisplay.ChartSpace1
    Do While .Charts.Count > 0
        ThisDisplay.ChartSpace1.Charts.Delete (0)
    Loop

    Set objChart = .Charts.Add
    objChart.HasTitle = True
    objChart.Title.Caption = "Chart Title"
    objChart.Axes.Item(0).HasTitle = True
    objChart.Axes.Item(1).HasTitle = True
    objChart.Axes.Item(0).Title.Caption = "Axis 0"
    objChart.Axes.Item(1).Title.Caption = "Axis 1"
    objChart.HasLegend = False        

    Dim astrHeaders(0 To 4) As String
    Dim aintValues1(0 To 4) As String
    Dim aintValues2(0 To 4) As String
    Dim astrSeries1(0) As String
    Dim astrSeries2(0) As String

    astrHeaders(0) = "AL1"
    astrHeaders(1) = "AL2"
    astrHeaders(2) = "AL3"
    astrHeaders(3) = "AL4"
    astrHeaders(4) = "AL5"

    astrSeries(0) = "Series Name"

    aintValues(0) = 1
    aintValues(1) = 3
    aintValues(2) = 17
    aintValues(3) = 1
    aintValues(4) = 7

    objChart.Type = .Constants.chChartTypeColumnClustered

    Call objChart.SetData(chDimSeriesName, .Constants.chDataLiteral, astrSeries)
    Call objChart.SetData(chDimCategories, .Constants.chDataLiteral, astrHeaders)
    Call objChart.SeriesCollection(0).SetData(.Constants.chDimValues, .Constants.chDataLiteral, aintValues)

End With  
End Sub


Public Sub AddValuesFromSpreadsheet()
Dim objChart1 As ChChart

With ThisDisplay.ChartSpace1
    Do While .Charts.Count > 0
        ThisDisplay.ChartSpace1.Charts.Delete (0)
    Loop

    Set .DataSource = ThisDisplay.sstChartData

    Set objChart1 = .Charts.Add
    ' Set the chart type.
    objChart1.Type = .Constants.chChartTypeColumnClustered

    ' Display titles
    objChart1.HasTitle = True
    objChart1.Title.Caption = "Chart Title"

    ' Bind the series name to cell B1 in the first sheet of the spreadsheet
    objChart1.SetData chDimSeriesNames, .Constants.chDataBound, "B1"

    ' Bind the category axis to cell A2:A28 in the first sheet of the spreadsheet.
    objChart1.SetData chDimCategories, .Constants.chDataBound, "A2:A6"

    ' Bind the values of the data series to cells B2:B28 in the first sheet of the spreadsheet.
    objChart1.SeriesCollection(0).SetData chDimValues, .Constants.chDataBound, "B2:B6"

End With
End Sub
```